# How to pass multiple constants and variables to Scipy Optimize?

Tags: python, scipy-optimize

I am trying to fit model data (calculated from `eR`) to my experimental data `e_exp`. I am not quite sure how to pass constants and variables to `func`.

```
import numpy as np
import math
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit, least_squares, minimize

f_exp     = np.array([1, 1.6, 2.7, 4.4, 7.3, 12, 20, 32, 56, 88, 144, 250000])
e_exp     = np.array([7.15, 7.30, 7.20, 7.25, 7.26, 7.28, 7.32, 7.25, 7.35, 7.34, 7.37, 13.55])

ezero     = np.min(e_exp)
einf      = np.max(e_exp)

ig_fc     = 500
ig_alpha  = 0.35

def CCER(einf, ezero, f_exp, fc, alpha):
    x  = [np.log(_ / ig_fc) for _ in f_exp]
    eR = [ezero + 1/2 * (einf - ezero) * (1 + np.sinh((1 - ig_alpha) * _) / (np.cosh((1 - ig_alpha) * _) + np.sin(1/2 * ig_alpha * math.pi))) for _ in x]
    return eR

def func(z):
    return np.sum((CCER(z[0], z[1], z[2], z[3], z[4], z[5]) - e_exp) ** 2)

res = minimize(func, (ig_fc, ig_alpha), method='SLSQP')
```

`einf`, `ezero`, and `f_exp` are all constant plus the variables I need to optimize are `ig_fc` and `ig_alpha`, in which `ig` stands for initial guess.

How can I make this work?

I am also not sure which of the optimization algorithms from `scipy` are best suited for my problem (be it `curve_fit`, `least_squares` or `minimize`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you want is the following:

```
def CCER(x, fc, alpha):
    y = np.log(x/fc)
    eR = ezero + 1/2 * (einf - ezero) * (1 + np.sinh((1 - alpha) * y) / (np.cosh((1 - alpha) * y) + np.sin(1/2 * alpha * math.pi)))
    return eR

res = curve_fit(CCER, f_exp, e_exp, p0=(ig_fc, ig_alpha))
```

You're passing the first value to `CCER` as an argument, the two remaining ones (`fc` and `alpha`) are then treated as optimizable parameters. All fixed parameters will be read from the outer scope - no need to pass them explicitly to the function here.

Finally, in `curve_fit` you only need to pass an array of inputs (`f_exp`) and corresponding outputs (`e_exp`), as well as - possibly - a tuple of initial guesses `p0`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @Miłosz Wieczór. I have a bit of trouble understanding exactly what is going on since `einf` and `ezero` are not defined as inputs. Also, are `res[0][0]` and `res[0][1]` the respective `fc` and `alpha` that being subject to optimization?

Comment: When not found in the local scope of the function, Python will try to search for `einf` and `ezero` in the outer scopes, i.e., the global scope in this case. This is why you don't have to pass them as arguments. Regarding the output, by looking up the documentation: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html you shall see that the first array (`res[0]`) is indeed the list of optimized parameters, and the second (`res[1]`) reports the uncertainties.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, @Miłosz Wieczór! It makes sense to me now.

Comment: I have a follow-up question for you, @Miłosz Wieczór. What if instead of a vector, `e_exp` is, for example, a 2D array with shape `(2, 12)`? This would yield `einf` and `ezero`  not as single values anymore but with the shape `(2,1)`.  If I try to run this, I get `error: Result from function call is not a proper array of floats.`  This has to have something to do with how Python read the global variables. Is there a way to make it work with multiple  `e_exp` so that the calculations are performed on each of them? Thank you, and I apologize for ambushing you like this in the comment section.