# Joint-fit using curve_fit with multiple equations and inputs - Is it even possible?

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize, lmfit

I asked similar questions in [January](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59810790/how-to-pass-multiple-constants-and-variables-to-scipy-optimize) and [April](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61227277/simultaneous-optimization-of-two-different-functions-to-provide-a-universal-solu) that @Miłosz Wieczór and @Joe were kind enough to show interest in. Now, I am facing a similar but different problem because I need to do a joint-fit with multiple equations and inputs in order to get the universal solutions for two parameters `fc` and `alpha`. My code (which is based on the answers from the previous questions) is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import linalg
import math
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit, least_squares, minimize

ya_exp  = np.array([1, 1.3, 1.7, 2.1, 2.7, 3.5, 4.5, 5.8, 7.5, 9.7, 12, 16, 21, 27, 34, 44, 57, 73, 94, 120, 156, 250000])

yb_exp  = np.array([1, 1.3, 1.7, 2.1, 2.7, 3.5, 4.5, 5.8, 7.5, 9.7, 12, 16, 21, 27, 34, 44, 57, 73, 94, 120, 156])

xa1_exp = np.array([4.68, 4.70, 4.71, 4.72, 4.74, 4.75, 4.76, 4.77, 4.79, 4.80,
                    4.82, 4.83, 4.85, 4.87, 4.89, 4.90, 4.96, 4.99, 5.02, 5.06,
                    5.11, 6.23])

xb1_exp = np.array([0.018, 0.023, 0.019, 0.023, 0.022, 0.023, 0.023, 0.023, 0.023, 0.024,
                    0.025, 0.028, 0.032, 0.033, 0.034, 0.037, 0.040, 0.043, 0.045, 0.047,
                    0.049])

xa2_exp = np.array([7.01, 7.03, 7.04, 7.04, 7.04, 7.10, 7.13, 7.13, 7.16, 7.14,
                    7.19, 7.18, 7.19, 7.22, 7.24, 7.28, 7.32, 7.35, 7.40, 7.45,
                    7.49, 10.1])

xb2_exp = np.array([0.008, 0.009, 0.008, 0.009, 0.008, 0.010, 0.010, 0.010, 0.011, 0.012,
                    0.016, 0.017, 0.020, 0.023, 0.027, 0.029, 0.036, 0.040, 0.043, 0.046,
                    0.052])

xa3_exp = np.array([5.67, 5.67, 5.68, 5.69, 5.72, 5.74, 5.74, 5.76, 5.76, 5.79,
                    5.81, 5.81, 5.83, 4.86, 5.89, 5.91, 5.96, 6.00, 6.04, 6.10,
                    6.14, 7.56])

xb3_exp = np.array([0.011, 0.011, 0.012, 0.011, 0.012, 0.012, 0.012, 0.012, 0.015, 0.017,
                    0.021, 0.026, 0.028, 0.030, 0.036, 0.039, 0.046, 0.050, 0.056, 0.059,
                    0.063])

xa1_zero = np.min(xa1_exp)
xa1_inf  = np.max(xa1_exp)

xa2_zero = np.min(xa2_exp)
xa2_inf  = np.min(xa2_exp)

xa3_zero = np.min(xa3_exp)
xa3_inf  = np.min(xa3_exp)

ig_fc    = 500
ig_alpha = 0.35

def CCXA(f_exp, fc, alpha):
    x  = np.log(f_exp/fc)
    R  = xa_zero + 1/2 * (xa_inf - xa_zero) * (1 + np.sinh((1 - alpha) * x) / (np.cosh((1 - alpha) * x) + np.sin(1/2 * alpha * math.pi)))
    I  = 1/2 * (xa_inf - xa_zero) * np.cos(alpha * math.pi / 2) / (np.cosh((1 - alpha) * x) + np.sin(alpha * math.pi / 2))
    RI = np.sqrt(R ** 2 + I ** 2)
    return RI

def CCXB(f_exp, fc, alpha):
    x  = np.log(f_exp/fc)
    R  = xa_zero + 1/2 * (xa_inf - xa_zero) * (1 + np.sinh((1 - alpha) * x) / (np.cosh((1 - alpha) * x) + np.sin(1/2 * alpha * math.pi)))
    I  = 1/2 * (xa_inf - xa_zero) * np.cos(alpha * math.pi / 2) / (np.cosh((1 - alpha) * x) + np.sin(alpha * math.pi / 2))
    iQ = I / R
    return iQ

poptXA, pcovXA = curve_fit(CCXA, ya_exp, xa_exp, p0=(ig_fc, ig_alpha))

poptXB, pcovXB = curve_fit(CCXB, yb_exp, xb_exp, p0=(ig_fc, ig_alpha))

def objective(e_exp, f_exp):
    poptXA, pcovXA = curve_fit(CCXA, ya_exp, xa_exp, p0=(ig_fc, ig_alpha))

    poptXB, pcovXB = curve_fit(CCXB, yb_exp, xb_exp, p0=(ig_fc, ig_alpha))
    
    err_total = np.sum(np.sqrt(np.diag(pcovXA))) + np.sum(np.sqrt(np.diag(pcovXB)))

    delta = linalg.norm(poptXB - poptXA)
    
    return err_total, delta

test = objective(xa_exp, ya_exp)
```

My first problem is that I am not sure how to make `CCXA` and `CCXB` search and locate `xa_exp` and `xb_exp` from the global scope because the different variables are defined by other names: `xa1_exp`, `xa2_exp`, and `xa3_exp` plus `xb1_exp`, `xb2_exp`, and `xb2_exp`. Again, I am interested in `fc` and `alpha` as optimizable parameters. `curve_fit(CCXA, ya_exp, xa_exp, p0=(ig_fc, ig_alpha))` is able to optimize for `fc` and `alpha` but relies on `xa_exp` and `xb_exp` from the global scope. How can I pass these to the functions when they are different? Also, notice that the length of `ya_exp`, `xa1_exp`, `xa2_exp`, and `xa3_exp` is `22` while the length of `yb_exp`, `xb1_exp`, `xb2_exp`, and `xb3_exp` is `21`.

My second problem is that I have no idea how to write a `function` that uses `curve_fit` as a global joint-fit that includes all the values. In other words, I want to find the best universal fits for `fc` and `alpha` for all the all the values, so that I get one global (or universal?) fit instead of six independent fits. `objective` provides `test[0]=poptXB[0]-poptXA[0]`, while `test[1]` is the norm of `popXA` and `poptXB`, but neither `returns` provide the fitted values for `fc` and `alpha`, which is what I seek.

Is this possible?

---

EDIT 26.08.2020 (and 30.08.2020)

I came across another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59810790/how-to-pass-multiple-constants-and-variables-to-scipy-optimize) regarding joint fit and adjusted my code accordingly:

```
from lmfit import minimize, Parameters, fit_report

params = Parameters()
params.add('fc', value=500)
params.add('alpha', value=0.2)

def CCXA(f_exp, xa_zero, xa_inf, fc, alpha):
    x  = np.log(f_exp/fc)
    R  = xa_zero + 1/2 * (xa_inf - xa_zero) * (1 + np.sinh((1 - alpha) * x) / (np.cosh((1 - alpha) * x) + np.sin(1/2 * alpha * math.pi)))
    I  = 1/2 * (xa_inf - xa_zero) * np.cos(alpha * math.pi / 2) / (np.cosh((1 - alpha) * x) + np.sin(alpha * math.pi / 2))
    RI = np.sqrt(R ** 2 + I ** 2)
    return RI

def CCXB(f_exp, xa_zero, xa_inf, fc, alpha):
    x  = np.log(f_exp/fc)
    R  = xa_zero + 1/2 * (xa_inf - xa_zero) * (1 + np.sinh((1 - alpha) * x) / (np.cosh((1 - alpha) * x) + np.sin(1/2 * alpha * math.pi)))
    I  = 1/2 * (xa_inf - xa_zero) * np.cos(alpha * math.pi / 2) / (np.cosh((1 - alpha) * x) + np.sin(alpha * math.pi / 2))
    iQ = I / R
    return iQ

def fit_function(params, ya_data=None, xa1_data=None, xa2_data=None, xa3_data=None, yb_data=None, xb1_data=None, xb2_data=None, xb3_data=None):
    xa_data = np.array([xa1_data, xa2_data, xa3_data])
    modxa   = np.array([CCXA(ya_data, np.min(i), np.max(i), params['fc'], params['alpha']) for i in xa_data])
    #sigma   = np.array([1 / np.sqrt(i+1) for i in xa_data])
    #sigma   = np.full((1,22), 0.5)
    #resxa   = np.array([(i - j)/k for i, j, k in zip(xa_data, modxa, sigma)])
    resxa   = np.array([i - j for i, j in zip(xa_data, modxa)])
    
    xb_data = np.array([xb1_data, xb2_data, xb3_data]) 
    modxb   = np.array([CCXB(yb_data, np.min(i), np.max(i), params['fc'], params['alpha']) for i in xa_data])
    #sigmb   = np.array([1 / np.sqrt(i+1) for i in xb_data])
    #sigmb   = np.full((1,21), 1)
    #resxb   = np.array([(i - j)/k for i, j, k in zip(xb_data, modxb, sigmb)])
    resxb   = np.array([i - j for i, j in zip(xb_data, modxb)])
    
    return np.concatenate((resxa.ravel(), resxb.ravel()))
```

Minor modifications of `CCXA` and `CCXB` plus the introduction of `fit_function` that is solved using `lmfit` provided values for `fc` and `alpha`:

```
[[Fit Statistics]]
    # fitting method   = leastsq
    # function evals   = 23
    # data points      = 129
    # variables        = 2
    chi-square         = 8.89790022
    reduced chi-square = 0.07006221
    Akaike info crit   = -340.945624
    Bayesian info crit = -335.225999
[[Variables]]
    fc:     1149.59953 +/- 572.031178 (49.76%) (init = 500)
    alpha:  0.64118507 +/- 0.04236375 (6.61%) (init = 0.5)
[[Correlations]] (unreported correlations are < 0.100)
    C(fc, alpha) =  0.874
```

Since I am new to `lmfit`, I would like to know if this is how it is supposed to be used. Is what I did correct or is it completely wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, your use of lmfit and `np.concatenate()` looks right to me to find the single set of parameter values that will minimize the residual of (model1, dataset1) and (model2, dataset2).   I'm not entirely sure that I understand your model and the 3 `x` values.  I think it might be done more efficiently, but that's sort of a different question of whether the fitting mechanics are doing what you intend - I think they are.

The next (trickier) question is whether you want to emphasize a misfit in one dataset more than the other.  As written, your function asserts that all data points are equally weighted - that is a fine default approach, but may not always be the case.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying, @M Newville. I am also sure it could be done more efficient but I am a novice. I thought about using weights as well to "prioritize" `xb_data` over `xa_data` in the joint-fit procedure. How would I do that with this many datasets? Do I have to put individual weights on each of the six datasets?

Comment: yes, you could simply multiply the residuals for each dataset by a different weighting factor to make a misfit in one dataset more important than a misfit in another dataset.  it is not uncommon to weight by `1/uncertainty_in_data`  (if you have those values) so that a misfit in noisier or "less certain" data is less important than a misfit in cleaner, more certain data.

Comment: Thank you again, @M Newville. Despite feeling bad for taking so much of your time, I have another question. Unlike `Model`, `minimize` does not take any weights directly as inputs. It also seems that my problem is better suited for `minimize` and not `Model`. I need to define some sort of `sigma` and return `resxa=(data-model)/sigma` instead of `resxa=data-model`. How do I implement this if I want to focus the fit on primarily the `xb_data` and secondary the `xa_data`? Do I, for example, define `sigma=np.full((1,21), 0.5)` and `sigmb=np.full((1,21), 1` for `resxa` and `resxb`?

Comment: with `minimize` your objective function returns the array to be minimized, so you will have to apply any weighting yourself.   So, concatenate the appropriate `(data-model)/sigma` values for the two different datasets.

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier to use  least_squares directly. It takes a vector of residuals, where you simply specify the l.h.s. of your two equations

Comment: Thank you for your response, @ev-br. I am not sure that I follow. Since I have two equations, I also have two left-hand sides. How exactly do I combine them using `least_squares` from `scipy`? I apologize for my ignorance.

Comment: The vector of residuals has the length of twice the number of observations